# Can we register icon overlay at user level?

Tags: c++, windows, icons

I want to display icon overlay in user context and my software installs without admin access.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible icon overlays are system level refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127455%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Notice that you need admin access to add the keys mentioned in the link as well as the registry path in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE which will enable the effect all users. This behavior is the same for Windows Vista, 7 and 8.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot register your overlay handler without admin access, but since explorer.exe runs with current user's credentials, you can implement some configuration checking in order to display the overlay (or not).

For example, you can check for a particular key under HKCU or for a configuration file under %APPDATA% folder.